# gnome-control-center removed together with totem

Tags: apt, 17.10

When removing totem package from clean Ubuntu 17.10 installation, package gnome-control-center is removed too, together with ubuntu-desktop.
Can you explain why is it selected / removed ?

Totem package is [not dependent on it](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/totem)

```
vm@vm-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt purge "totem.*"
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libtotem-dev' for regex 'totem.*'
Note, selecting 'libtotem-plparser-dev' for regex 'totem.*'
Note, selecting 'totem-plugins-extra' for regex 'totem.*'
Note, selecting 'totem-gstreamer' for regex 'totem.*'
Note, selecting 'libtotem-pg5' for regex 'totem.*'
Note, selecting 'libtotem-plparser-videosite' for regex 'totem.*'
Note, selecting 'libtotem-plparser-common' for regex 'totem.*'
Note, selecting 'gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0' for regex 'totem.*'
Note, selecting 'libtotem-plparser17' for regex 'totem.*'
Note, selecting 'libtotem-plparser18' for regex 'totem.*'
Note, selecting 'totem-plugins' for regex 'totem.*'
Note, selecting 'libtotem0' for regex 'totem.*'
Note, selecting 'gir1.2-totem-1.0' for regex 'totem.*'
Note, selecting 'libtotem-pg-dev' for regex 'totem.*'
Note, selecting 'totem-common' for regex 'totem.*'
Note, selecting 'totem' for regex 'totem.*'
Package 'totem-gstreamer' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libtotem-plparser17' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libtotem-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libtotem-pg-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libtotem-pg5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libtotem-plparser-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libtotem-plparser-videosite' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'totem-plugins-extra' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gir1.2-totem-1.0* gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0*
  gnome-control-center* grilo-plugins-0.3-base* libgrilo-0.3-0*
  libtotem-plparser-common* libtotem-plparser18* libtotem0*
  totem* totem-common* totem-plugins* ubuntu-desktop*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 12 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
After this operation, 13,5 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`gnome-control-center`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/gnome-control-center) depends on [`libgrilo-0.3-0`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/libgrilo-0.3-0), which depends on `libtotem-plparser18`, and your output clearly states:

```
Note, selecting 'libtotem-plparser18' for regex 'totem.*'
```